# What is the equivalent of SPLIT-APPLY-COMBINE in PostgreSQL

Tags: pandas, postgresql

## TLDR;

What is the equivalent of the following Python code snippet in PostgreSQL?

```py
df.groupby('column').apply(function)
```

Where `df` is a Pandas DataFrame instance.

## Context

I am used to the [Split-Apply-Combine Paradigm](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html) in Python and want to apply the same framework in PostgreSQL.

Suppose I have the following table with a time, place, and measurement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (place VARCHAR(10), time TIMESTAMP, measurement FLOAT);
TRUNCATE test_table;
INSERT INTO test_table
       VALUES ('A', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 1.0),
              ('A', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:15:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 2.0),
              ('A', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 2.0),
              ('A', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:45:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 2.0),
              ('A', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 3.0),
              ('B', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 3.0),
              ('B', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:15:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 2.0),
              ('B', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 2.0),
              ('B', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:45:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 2.0),
              ('B', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 3.0),
              ('C', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 1.0),
              ('C', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:15:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 2.0),
              ('C', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 2.0),
              ('C', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 00:45:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 2.0),
              ('C', TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 01:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 3.0);
```

Associated to each `place` is a timeseries. Sometimes the measurement device at a given place will flatline and my goal is to move the flatline rows to another table.

I have written the following query to get the table I want for a given place.

```sql
SELECT place, time, measurement
       FROM (SELECT place, time, measurement, LEAD(measurement, 1) OVER (ORDER BY time) AS leading_measurement
             FROM test_table WHERE place = 'A') q
       WHERE NOT measurement = leading_measurement OR leading_measurement IS NULL;
```

Within the query I had a subquery with a clause `WHERE place = 'A'` because the cleaning algorithm would detect the last row of `A` as being the same as the first row of `B` and I would not want to remove that row. But this also means I have not "cleaned" the other two places.

In theory I would like to `GROUP BY place` run the query, and union the results. However the `GROUP BY` clause only supports aggregate functions and my query returns multiple rows. I want to somehow `SELECT DISTINCT(place)` and run a for loop over that list. The Python equivalent is:

```py
test_table.groupby('place') \
          .apply(lambda place: 
                 place[place["measurement"].diff(1) != 0])
```

I can (and have) been using Python to export to CSV then import the CSV into PSQL tables but my boss would greatly appreciate it done in PostgreSQL.

I would appreciate any guidence, even a link to a relevant manual page.

Comment: It can't easily be done in SQL. You *could* write a stored procedure, but it would be messy. I strongly advise you stick with python.  You have an operational requirement, which should be met by an operational solution. SQL is not a good choice for an operational solution. If it ain't busted, don't fix it.

Comment: @Bohemian Mahalo nui loa for your input. I will discuss if SQL is the appropriate tool for the work to my boss tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not give up on SQL quite so quickly.  
If I understand correctly you want to to copy to another table then delete those rows which have the same measurement by place and time. So for Place A move then delete the rows with times `00:30:00 and 00:40:00`. This is because those are the same as time stamp `00:15:00`. With similar copy and delete for Place B and Place C.  
If this is correct then it is quite easily done in SQL, at least Postgres SQL. It can be done in a single statement. Postgres SQL permits DML operations is a CTE. This allows you write a CTE to identify the rows to process in the first table, then use that CTE to insert those rows onto the second table, and finally use the same CTE to delete from the first table. (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cd8140216eb32d62881629abdcc72d39))

```
with to_move(rctid) as 
     ( select ctid
       from (select place, time, measurement 
                  , lead(measurement, 1) over (partition by place order by time) as leading_measurement, ctid
               from test_table
            ) q  
        where  measurement = leading_measurement
     )  
    , movers as 
      ( insert into test_table_flat (place, time, measurement) 
          select t.place, t.time, t.measurement 
            from test_table t 
           where t.ctid in (select rctid from to_move) 
      ) 
delete 
  from test_table 
 where ctid in (select rctid from to_move) ;
```